# Rangy library set selected the start offset of the next node

Tags: javascript, range, rangy

I have:

```
<div class="content-sms"><p contenteditable="true">Hellow! <span>#name</span>, you are welcome to the <span>#place</span>.</p></div>
```

I need to select the start offset of the next node when i type space key inside `span`.

Example: when I am typing into `<span>#name[selected here]</span>`, and I press the space key I want to select this position `<span>#name</span>[selected here], you are welcome to the`.

Here is the two methods that i created to do it:

```
constructor(){
    this.contentSms = this.form.find(".content-sms > p");

    this.contentSms.on("keyup", this.onTypingEditor);
}

//event on keyUp of editor 
onTypingEditor(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    let keyCode = event.keyCode;

    //if space typed
    if (keyCode === 32) {
        //get the selected node
        let selectedNode = this.getElementNodeSelected();
        //if selected node is a span tag
        if (this.isHighLightNode(selectedNode)){
            //execute this method
            this.selectAfterNode(selectedNode);
        }
    }
}

/*
here is the method that i create to try select the next node.
there is an object this.rangeEditor, it is the range object of
my editor
*/
selectAfterNode(node){
    let sel = rangy.getSelection();

    this.rangeEditor.selectNode(node);
    let nextNode = this.rangeEditor.commonAncestorContainer.nextSibling;
    this.rangeEditor.selectNode(nextNode);
    this.rangeEditor.collapse(1);

    sel.addRange(this.rangeEditor);
}
```

I am using ES6, i hope you can help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any code that you've tried so far? Having code to work from always helps with answering questions! :)

Comment: Yes i have, i will edit to insert it

Comment: Sorry the late, i edited like you ask me. I don't know how i get the next node of the node selected. When outside `span` selected I can get the next node, because `nextSibling` returns to me the `span`, but when the `span` is selected the `nextSibling` returns `null`.

Comment: You could try `nextNode = this.rangeEditor.commonAncestorContainer.parentNode.nextSibling`